# c++: Function is ambiguous when passing pointers to vectors

Tags: c++, stdvector

In my program I have a function that works with two vectors (actually, the program must sum two numbers which have a huge amount of digits but I think it is not relevant to that). Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void plus (vector <int> *n1, vector <int> *n2)
{
    // my code here
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int i;
    vector <int> n1, n2;
    for (i = 1; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        n1.push_back (i);
    }
    for (i = 9; i > 5; --i)
    {
        n2.push_back (i);
    }
    plus (&n1, &n2);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, it says that "reference to 'plus' is ambiguous". What is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `using namespace std;` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While all the answers given here are technically correct, I think there is only one sustainable solution:

Remove `using namespace std;`. Unfortunately, using this is taught by lots of tutorials and books, but it comes with many problems, one of which you have just witnessed. For a better overview of `using` and namespaces, read Herb Sutter's article on this issue: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/migrating_to_namespaces.htm

Answer (score 2):

There is a function `std::plus` which is confusing the compiler.

Rename your function or say `::plus` to call it.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/plus/

`plus` is a function in standard C++ library.

Avoid it with `::plus`

Answer (score 1):

When a function is "ambiguous," it means that there already exists a function of that same name and structure. So, as others mentioned, std::plus is conflicting with your definition, and the compiler doesn't know which to use.

Rename the method, or call `::plus`.